# How can I parse a jagged array to individual variables in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I have a jagged array that has a minimum of three elements, and I need to parse out the first five elements, filling any nulls with a space.

```
 // there will ALWAYS be three elements 
String whiconcatC = scrubbedInputArray[0];
String whiconcatD = scrubbedInputArray[1];
String whiconcatE = scrubbedInputArray[2];

 // there MAY be a fourth or fifth element
if (scrubbedInputTokens > 3) {
String whiconcatF = scrubbedInputArray[3];
} else {
String whiconcatF = " ";
}
 //
if (scrubbedInputTokens > 4) {
String whiconcatG = scrubbedInputArray[4];
} else {
String whiconcatG = " ";
}
```

While the above code does not generate errors during compile, subsequent lines referencing `whiconcatF` or `whiconcatG` will error out during compile with `cannot find symbol`.

I've tried using `forEach` and `StringTokenizer` (after converting the array to a delimited string), but can't figure out how to work a default value in the instance that there's no value in spots 4 & 5.

I've not been able to figure out any other way to do this nor why my if logic is failing. Suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, david, that did it. A scope issue.

Comment: you may want to initialize them, to avoid null pointer exceptions.

Comment: @david - You should avoid editing the question, such that it fixes the error itself. This would render the answers given below totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats because they have local scope and are defined inside brackets. Thus the die when you close the brackets and are not reachable. Define them outside and you should be fine.

```
String whiconcatC = scrubbedInputArray[0];
String whiconcatD = scrubbedInputArray[1];
String whiconcatE = scrubbedInputArray[2];
String whiconcatF = "";
String whiconcatG = "";


// there MAY be a fourth or fifth element
if (scrubbedInputTokens > 3) {
whiconcatF = scrubbedInputArray[3];   
} else {
whiconcatF = " ";
}
//
if (scrubbedInputTokens > 4) {
whiconcatG = scrubbedInputArray[4];
} else {
whiconcatG = " ";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Declare the `whiconcatF` outside the `if-else` for them to visible beyond it. Currently both the String variables are within the scope of `if` and `else` only. Once its moved above the `if`, it gets the method level scope(I hope this whole snippet is not within any other block), and thus you can access them anywhere in the method.

```
String whiconcatF = " "; // Default value
if (scrubbedInputTokens > 3) {
    whiconcatF = scrubbedInputArray[3];
}

String whiconcatG = " "; // Default value
if (scrubbedInputTokens > 4) {
    whiconcatG = scrubbedInputArray[4];
}
```

Since you have default values now, you can remove the `else` part for both the `if`.

Comment: looks like someone already made that change to my code....scope. It's always scope... ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Done!:) I had moved out of my place after the posting the answer initially, hence couldn't clean up immediately!

Comment: @dwwilson66-please don't encourage such edits to the question because if the error itself is removed from the question, it no longer is a question and all the answers posted for that, become irrelevant. Hope you understand.

Comment: Completely. Wasn't quite sure how to handle it...so I made sure to comment that a change had been made. Unfortunately, my rep doesn't allow me to disapprove edits yet... :(